# Are there any good, open-source change request systems?

Tags: open-source, development-process, documentation, change

I have a need to make a somewhat custom change request system (very high auditing requirements).

Instead of completely reinventing the wheel I was wondering if there's an open-source change request system, considered decent that I could write a custom module for?

I've done some searching but the ones I have found don't seem to encapsulate what a change request system should be (no way of recording test plans or work streams).

<sub>In my experience a change request system has (does) store test plans / technical specs and a log of work.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use jira (10 users for 10 bucks) and it is great. We track almost everything in it. Bugs/ Tasks/ Feature requests.

Okay... it's not open source but these guys build like crazy and it just works out of the box.

We tried a lot of open source apps... but non really worked like we would like it to work.

Just give it a try... it's just 10 bucks :-)

http://www.atlassian.com/company/customers/?tab=jira

Comment: Holy cow... This looks pretty bang on... Thank-you!

Comment: We've been using jira at work. It is ok but sometimes buggy. I think a combination of bugzilla and review board can be as effective.

Comment: Yeah the atlassian products are pretty sweet.  The combination of jira/confluence/crucible has been awesome for us.

Answer (score 3):

Would a change request system differ greatly from an issue tracking system?

For a general web based feature tracking/issue tracking system I find mantis to be good.

The code is procedural, the UI is ugly, but it works and it's easy to modify.

http://www.mantisbt.org/

Comment: In my experience a change request system has (does) store test plans / technical specs and a log of work. This would be related to features only. Maybe this terminology is just associated with my work and isn't an industry standard though?

Comment: I just laughed at this "I find mantis to be good" ... "The code is procedural and the UI is ugly" ;) +1 for a good suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Is it something related to Bug Tracking System?

If you are looking for something like that with some extensions, i would advice to look at the followings - [Top 10 Open Source Bug Tracking System](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system/).

There is also an alternative Change Request Management tool from SourceForge.net that you may extend as required - [Change Request Management](http://changerequest.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The Change Request Management tool that you mention has no files associated with it. It would require an awful lot of "extending."